# How to fix the error Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body when I invoke a suspend fun in setOnInfoListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The following code is to record a sound and save an item to database in Android Studio project with Room,  and system will stop record and save item to database automatically when a maximum duration had been setup and has now been reached.

But the code receives the error information:

*Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body*

How can I fix it?

```
override suspend fun startRecord(updateElapsedTime: UpdateElapsedTime) {

        with(mRecorder) {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            setMaxDuration(1000 * 60 * recordMaxValue);   
            setOutputFile(filename);

            setOnInfoListener { mr, what, extra ->
                if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {                   
                    completeRecord(updateElapsedTime)     //It causes error
                }
            }

            prepare()
            start()
        }

    }


    override suspend fun completeRecord(updateElapsedTime: UpdateElapsedTime) {
        try {          
            mRecorder.stop()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
        saveRecord()
    }

    private suspend fun saveRecord() {
        val mInfo = MInfo()
        handleMInfo.add(mInfo)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lambda you pass to `setOnInfoListener` is not called inside your coroutine. It's called on whatever thread the listener's class wants to.

(In the case of MediaRecorder, it will be called on whatever thread was used to instantiate the MediaRecorder, unless that wasn't a LooperThread, in which case it will call it on the main thread.)

Since the listener code is not called in your coroutine, you cannot call suspend functions in it. You must launch a new coroutine in the listener to call a suspend function. You must use a CoroutineScope that is appropriate for the lifetime of your MediaRecorder if you want to avoid leaking the MediaRecorder.